Cannot send k6 metrics to datadog agent
In my Github Actions workflow I am running a k6 script that's supposed to write metrics to Datadog. However I am getting the error
level=error msg="Couldn't flush a batch" error="write udp 127.0.0.1:33547->127.0.0.1:8125: write: connection refused"
This is the step in my workflow, it first runs the datadog/agent Docker container exposing port 8125/udp to which k6 then tries to send the metrics to:
  - name: Run k6 script
    env:
      DD_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.DD_API_KEY }}
    run: |
      DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 \
      docker run -d \
      --name datadog-k6 \
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
      -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
      -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
      -e DD_SITE="datadoghq.eu" \
      -e DD_API_KEY=${{ secrets.DD_API_KEY }} \
      -e DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=1 \
      -e DD_TAGS="env:development version:foo" \
      -p 8125:8125/udp \
      datadog/agent:latest
      
      k6 run ./k6/test.js \
        -e K6_STATSD_ENABLE_TAGS=true \
        -e K6_STATSD_ADDR="0.0.0.0:8125" \
        -o statsd \
        --verbose
      docker stop datadog-k6
      docker rm datadog-k6

I am using a self-hosted runner on Github Actions so it might be a docker-inside-docker issue?
I noticed that the statsd output option is deprecated but I am expecting it to still work
Would it work to send the k6 metrics via HTTP to datadog and does someone have an example for that?
Thanks!
